# Curl no funciona de Ubuntu a Jenkins (instalado en Windows)

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, hook

Para hacer pruebas de integración continua he montado un *Subversion* en una máquina *Ubuntu 20.04*. Está levantado y funcionando correctamente.

En otro pc, he montado una máquina virtual con un *Windows Server 2016* donde he instalado *Sonarqube* y *Jenkins*, ambos configurados y funcionando correctamente, lanzo "manualmente" análisis desde Jenkins y se ejecutan correctamente y vuelcan los resultados en Sonar.

Cuando trato de hacer una ejecución remota desde *Ubuntu*, ejecutando el comando curl correspondiente:

```
curl --user admin:token http://192.168.1.99:8090/job/Nombre_job/build?token=token
```

El resultado es que no hace nada, es como si ni siquiera lanzara la petición, sin embargo, ejecuto la creación de un nuevo *QualityGate* en *Sonar* desde la misma máquina *Ubuntu*:

```
curl -u -X POST admin:admin “http://192.168.1.99:9000/api/qualitygates/create?name=MyQG”
```

Y se crea sin ningún problema.

La IP de Sonar es `199.168.1.99:9000` y la IP de Jenkins es `192.168.1.99:8090` (cambié el puerto de 8080 a 8090 por si ese fuera el problema, pero sigue sin funcionar).

No entiendo por qué en un caso funciona sin problema (*Sonarqube*) y en el otro parece como si estuviera bloqueado (Jenkins).

No hay proxys habilitados ni firewalls.

Lanzando el mismo comando curl en el servidor Windows (descargué curl para *Windows*), *Jenkins* ejecuta el job, quiero decir con esto que el comando está verificado y es el correcto, pero no hay conexión desde Ubuntu a Windows en este caso, en el caso de Sonar, como ya digo, se ejecuta sin problemas.

¿Alguien ha tenido algún problema similar?

Agradecería alguna pista para continuar con mis pruebas, la finalidad es que al hacer un commit a subversión se desencadene automáticamente la ejecución del análisis de ese código, pero si ni siquiera funciona la ejecución remota lanzando un curl "a mano", en el script pasaría lo mismo, pues al fin y al cabo en el script se lanza ese comando, pero parametrizado para que sepa que análisis debe ejecutar.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda y un saludo.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Israel-ICM, la edición de la pregunta por tu parte hace que sea mucho mas fácil interpretarla.

Comment: Tengo que añadir que al no poder solucionar el problema lo que hice fue copiar la máquina virtual al propio ordenador con Ubuntu donde está levantado el Apache con Subversion, y ahí ya funciona todo correctamente para poder hacer las pruebas que necesito hacer. Gracias en cualquier caso a todos los que se hayan interesado por esta pregunta y si finalmente consigo "descifrar el misterio", os lo haré saber.